# can we access non-static class from main() method in java?

Tags: java, oop, static

In this is if  make Node class as non-static , will main method will be able to access it.

```
class LinkedList
 {
    Node head; 


static class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int d)  { data = d;  next=null; } // Constructor
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{ ..............}
}
```

Comment: Yes. **If** you have an instance of the `LinkedList`.

Comment: You would have to do `LinkedList.Node n = new LinkedList().new Node();`

Comment: side issue: give that LinkedList class a different name to avoid a name clash with a key core class.

Comment: totally misunderstand what is static class. Put in google three words. Has nothing to static main

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Your comment is correct and undestandable for profs. but totally out of question level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can access your Node class from your main method, if you instantiate an object from your class. You can do it like that:

```
class LinkedList {

    Node head;

    class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int d)  { data = d;  next=null; } // Constructor
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Instantiate your object
        LinkedList.Node node = new LinkedList().new Node(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case `Node` is an inner class of the outer class `LinkedList`. They come in different flavors.

- as static
- as non-static

The difference is that a non-static class has access to the member of the outer class. For that the non-static class has an implicit reference to the outer class.

In your case, using a non-static inner class, would cause confusion because different Node instances may refer to different LinkedList. The sematics becomes crazy